# How to register CoroutineExceptionHandler via ServiceLoader?

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

The [CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/index.html) Kdoc says:

> By default, when no handler is installed, uncaught exception are
> handled in the following way:
>
> If exception is CancellationException then it is ignored (because that
> is the supposed mechanism to cancel the running coroutine)
>
> Otherwise:
>
> if there is a Job in the context, then Job.cancel is invoked;
>
> Otherwise, all instances of CoroutineExceptionHandler found via
> ServiceLoader and current thread’s Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler are
> invoked.

No details have been provided about "*all instances of CoroutineExceptionHandler found via ServiceLoader*" (it's not uncommon for Kotlin docs to touch the tip of the iceberg only). How would this be done?

I know about `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler`; that's not the question here.

Comment: If by serviceloader they mean [Java serviceloader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), then try to put in your project resource a file named `kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler`, and append a line containing the full name of your handler class (Ex: `my.project.MyHandler`). It should be enough, if your handler has a default constructor (without parameter).

Comment: @amanin You're close, but the suggested path is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP here, figured it out based on @amamin's comment, and the article [Creating Extensible Applications With the Java Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/extensible.html).

> To register your provider, you must create a provider configuration
> file in the JAR file's META-INF/services directory. The configuration
> file name should be the fully qualified binary name of the service's
> type. The binary name is simply the fully qualified class name in
> which each component of the name is separated by a . character, and
> nested classes are separated by a $ character.
>
> For example, if you implement the
> com.example.dictionary.spi.Dictionary service type, you should create
> a META-INF/services/com.example.dictionary.spi.Dictionary file. On
> separate lines within the file, list the fully qualified binary names
> of your concrete implementations.

Back to my question, I needed to create a `META-INF/services/kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler` file with a single line, the FQN of an implementation.